# How do I put a video as my wallpaper spanning across dual monitors in Arch Linux?

Tags: linux, arch-linux, desktop-customization

Ive seen lots of tools for example `wallset` and `feh` but I haven't been able to find a tool that allows me to have a video spanning across two monitors as the background.

maybe a tool that just lets me set a video wallpaper and include a monitor pram like this
`background --display DisplayPort-2 /path/to/video.mp4`